# Saving high quality images, doing live processing - what's the best approach?

Tags: ios, opencv, avfoundation

I'm still learning about AVFoundation, so I'm unsure how best I should approach the problem of needing to capture a high quality still image, but provide a low-quality preview video stream.

I've got an app that needs to take high quality images (`AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`), but process the preview video stream using OpenCV - for which a much lower resolution is acceptable. Simply using the base [OpenCV Video Camera class](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/highgui/src/cap_ios_video_camera.mm) is no good, as setting the `defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset` to `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` results in the full resolution frame being passed to `processImage` - which is very slow indeed.

How can I have a high-quality connection to the device that I can use for capturing the still image, and a low-quality connection that can be processed and displayed? A description of how I need to set up sessions/connections would be very helpful. Is there an open-source example of such an app?

Comment: If you're asking how to get a smaller preview image, while still maintaining the ability to grab a still photo, you can add both an AVCaptureStillImageOutput and an AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to your capture session (if targeting iOS 4.3+). For the normal video feed, you'll get the smaller preview frames, and then when you trigger the photo capture method this will switch to the full photo resolution. This is what I do internally in my GPUImage framework: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage and you can look at the SimplePhotoFilter example application to see this in action.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar - I grabbed the pixels in the delegate method, made a CGImageRef of them, then dispatched that to the normal priority queue, where it was modified. Since AVFoundation must be using a CADisplayLink for the callback method it has highest priority. In my particular case I was not grabbing all pixels so it worked on an iPhone 4 at 30fps. Depending on what devices you want to run you have number of pixels, fps, etc trade offs.

Another idea is to grab a power of 2 subset of pixels - for instance every 4th in each row and every 4th row. Again I did something similar in my app at 20-30fps. You can then further operate on this smaller image in dispatched blocks.

If this seems daunting offer a bounty for working code.

CODE:

```
// Image is oriented with bottle neck to the left and the bottle bottom on the right
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
#if 1   
    AVCaptureDevice *camera = [(AVCaptureDeviceInput *)[captureSession.inputs lastObject] device];
    if(camera.adjustingWhiteBalance || camera.adjustingExposure) NSLog(@"GOTCHA: %d %d", camera.adjustingWhiteBalance, camera.adjustingExposure);
    printf("foo\n");
#endif

    if(saveState != saveOne && saveState != saveAll) return;


    @autoreleasepool {
        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
        //NSLog(@"PE: value=%lld timeScale=%d flags=%x", prStamp.value, prStamp.timescale, prStamp.flags);

        /*Lock the image buffer*/
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0); 

        NSRange captureRange;
        if(saveState == saveOne) {
#if 0 // B G R A MODE ! 
NSLog(@"PIXEL_TYPE: 0x%lx", CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(imageBuffer));
uint8_t *newPtr = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
NSLog(@"ONE VAL %x %x %x %x", newPtr[0], newPtr[1], newPtr[2], newPtr[3]);
}
exit(0);
#endif
            [edgeFinder setupImageBuffer:imageBuffer];

            BOOL success = [edgeFinder delineate:1];

            if(!success) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ edgeFinder = nil; [delegate error]; });
                saveState = saveNone;
            } else 
                bottleRange = edgeFinder.sides;
                xRange.location = edgeFinder.shoulder;
                xRange.length = edgeFinder.bottom - xRange.location;

                NSLog(@"bottleRange 1: %@ neck=%d bottom=%d", NSStringFromRange(bottleRange), edgeFinder.shoulder, edgeFinder.bottom );
                //searchRows = [edgeFinder expandRange:bottleRange];

                rowsPerSwath = lrintf((bottleRange.length*NUM_DEGREES_TO_GRAB)*(float)M_PI/360.0f);
NSLog(@"rowsPerSwath = %d", rowsPerSwath);
                saveState = saveIdling;

                captureRange = NSMakeRange(0, [WLIPBase numRows]);
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                    {
                        [delegate focusDone];
                        edgeFinder = nil;
                        captureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
                    });
        } else {        
            NSInteger rows = rowsPerSwath;
            NSInteger newOffset = bottleRange.length - rows;
            if(newOffset & 1) {
                --newOffset;
                ++rows;
            }
            captureRange = NSMakeRange(bottleRange.location + newOffset/2, rows);
        }
        //NSLog(@"captureRange=%u %u", captureRange.location, captureRange.length);

        /*Get information about the image*/
        uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 
        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 

        // Note Apple sample code cheats big time - the phone is big endian so this reverses the "apparent" order of bytes
        CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, captureRange.length, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little); // Video in ARGB format

assert(newContext);

        uint8_t *newPtr = (uint8_t *)CGBitmapContextGetData(newContext);
        size_t offset   = captureRange.location * bytesPerRow;

        memcpy(newPtr, baseAddress + offset, captureRange.length * bytesPerRow);

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

        OSAtomicIncrement32(&totalImages);
        int32_t curDepth = OSAtomicIncrement32(&queueDepth);
        if(curDepth > maxDepth) maxDepth = curDepth;

#define kImageContext   @"kImageContext"
#define kState          @"kState"
#define kPresTime       @"kPresTime"

        CMTime prStamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);      // when it was taken?
        //CMTime deStamp = CMSampleBufferGetDecodeTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);          // now?

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            [NSValue valueWithBytes:&saveState objCType:@encode(saveImages)], kState,
            [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:(__bridge id)newContext], kImageContext,
            [NSValue valueWithBytes:&prStamp objCType:@encode(CMTime)], kPresTime,
            nil ];
        dispatch_async(imageQueue, ^
            {
                // could be on any thread now
                OSAtomicDecrement32(&queueDepth);

                if(!isCancelled) {
                    saveImages state; [(NSValue *)[dict objectForKey:kState] getValue:&state];
                    CGContextRef context; [(NSValue *)[dict objectForKey:kImageContext] getValue:&context];
                    CMTime stamp; [(NSValue *)[dict objectForKey:kPresTime] getValue:&stamp];

                    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); 
                    CGContextRelease(context);
                    UIImageOrientation orient = state == saveOne ? UIImageOrientationLeft : UIImageOrientationUp;
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef scale:1.0 orientation:orient]; // imageWithCGImage:  UIImageOrientationUp  UIImageOrientationLeft
                    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
                    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

                    // NSLog(@"STATE:[%d]: value=%lld timeScale=%d flags=%x", state, stamp.value, stamp.timescale, stamp.flags);

                    {
                        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", num];
                        NSString *path = [[wlAppDelegate snippetsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
                        BOOL ret = [data writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
//NSLog(@"WROTE %d err=%d w/time %f path:%@", num, ret, (double)stamp.value/(double)stamp.timescale, path);
                        if(!ret) {
                            ++errors;
                        } else {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                {
                                    if(num) [delegate progress:(CGFloat)num/(CGFloat)(MORE_THAN_ONE_REV * SNAPS_PER_SEC) file:path];
                                } );
                        }
                        ++num;
                    }
                } else NSLog(@"CANCELLED");

            } );
    }
}
```

Comment: I take it in my case this would be achieved by overriding `captureOutput`, it's just a question of changing how the image is generated.

Comment: Doing this on ipad now no code handy. That sounds like the method name. You get access to the pixels there and have some small amount of time to copy them. Grabbing a fraction goes fast - doing a vImage size reduction will go very slow, relatively. With the fraction you cut down memory usage by 4 each reduction. Then later you can further reduce with a quality function if you really need to, however I'm going to guess that the power of two may be all you need.

Comment: Powers of two sounds great, currently the `CVImageBufferRef` is grabbed using `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer`, do you know if there's an equivalent of this function that allows me to specify a sample size (similar to the `inSampleSize` you can pass to `BitmapFactory` in Android)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to get all or nothing, so you'll have to do the code. I can post the guts of what I did in an hour or so if you want to see it...

Comment: That would be much appreciated. I'm more than happy to bounty this post when I can!

Comment: No need for a bounty unless you WANT someone (me :-) ) to code the "take every other pixel" etc.

Answer (score 0):

In AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto it use small video preview(about 1000x700 for iPhone6) and high resolution photo(about 3000x2000).

So I use modified 'CvPhotoCamera' class to process small preview and take photo of full-size picture. I post this code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31478505/1994445