# iOS Still Image Capture Using CVVideoCamera (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, ios7, capture

I use opencv 2.4.9 for iOS and need help.

I would like to capture with CVVideoCamera during filming high-resolution photos. I need the video camera for the process image method to add a mature document capture via edge detection. This works great as well but i need a photo of the recognized high-resolution photo of the document once the document has been detected.

i found this http://code.opencv.org/svn/gsoc2012/ios/trunk/HelloWorld_iOS/HelloWorld_iOS/VideoCameraController.m

this works with photo and Video for the same time, but the process image Method is different as the from the cvvideocamera delegate and my algorithmus dont work with this class :- /

But i search this photocamera/videocamera solution for CVVideoCamera in OpenCV.

Hope for help and sorry for my english

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem adding some methods of `cvVideoCamera` class to `cvPhotoCamera` class. It works for me, but maybe need some improvements applying to you code.

**CvPhotoCameraMod.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>
#import <opencv2/highgui/ios.h>

#define DEGREES_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)

@class CvPhotoCameraMod;

@protocol CvPhotoCameraDelegateMod <CvPhotoCameraDelegate>
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image;
@end

@interface CvPhotoCameraMod : CvPhotoCamera <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) CALayer *customPreviewLayer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoDataOutput;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CvPhotoCameraDelegateMod> delegate;

- (void)createCustomVideoPreview;

@end
```

**CvPhotoCameraMod.mm:**

```
#import "CvPhotoCameraMod.h"
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#define DEGREES_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)

@implementation CvPhotoCameraMod


-(void)createCaptureOutput;
{
    [super createCaptureOutput];
    [self createVideoDataOutput];
}
- (void)createCustomVideoPreview;
{
    [self.parentView.layer addSublayer:self.customPreviewLayer];
}


//Method mostly taken from this source: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/b46719b0931b256ab68d5f833b8fadd83737ddd1/modules/videoio/src/cap_ios_video_camera.mm

-(void)createVideoDataOutput{
    // Make a video data output
    self.videoDataOutput = [AVCaptureVideoDataOutput new];

    //Drop grayscale support here
    self.videoDataOutput.videoSettings  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];


    // discard if the data output queue is blocked (as we process the still image)
    [self.videoDataOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
    if ( [self.captureSession canAddOutput:self.videoDataOutput] ) {
        [self.captureSession addOutput:self.videoDataOutput];
    }
    [[self.videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setEnabled:YES];

    // set video mirroring for front camera (more intuitive)
    if ([self.videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].supportsVideoMirroring) {
        if (self.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
            [self.videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].videoMirrored = YES;
        } else {
            [self.videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].videoMirrored = NO;
        }
    }

    // set default video orientation
    if ([self.videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].supportsVideoOrientation) {
        [self.videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].videoOrientation = self.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation;
    }

    // create a custom preview layer
    self.customPreviewLayer = [CALayer layer];

    self.customPreviewLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.parentView.frame.size.width, self.parentView.frame.size.height);

    self.customPreviewLayer.position = CGPointMake(self.parentView.frame.size.width/2., self.parentView.frame.size.height/2.);

    // create a serial dispatch queue used for the sample buffer delegate as well as when a still image is captured
    // a serial dispatch queue must be used to guarantee that video frames will be delivered in order
    // see the header doc for setSampleBufferDelegate:queue: for more information
    dispatch_queue_t videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [self.videoDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:videoDataOutputQueue];
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    (void)captureOutput;
    (void)connection;
    if (self.delegate) {

        // convert from Core Media to Core Video
        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

        void* bufferAddress;
        size_t width;
        size_t height;
        size_t bytesPerRow;

        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
        CGContextRef context;

        int format_opencv;

        OSType format = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(imageBuffer);
        if (format == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange) {

            format_opencv = CV_8UC1;

            bufferAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
            width = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
            height = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
            bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);

        } else { // expect kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA

            format_opencv = CV_8UC4;

            bufferAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
            width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
            height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
            bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);

        }

        // delegate image processing to the delegate
        cv::Mat image((int)height, (int)width, format_opencv, bufferAddress, bytesPerRow);

        CGImage* dstImage;

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(processImage:)]) {
            [self.delegate processImage:image];
        }

        // check if matrix data pointer or dimensions were changed by the delegate
        bool iOSimage = false;
        if (height == (size_t)image.rows && width == (size_t)image.cols && format_opencv == image.type() && bufferAddress == image.data && bytesPerRow == image.step) {
            iOSimage = true;
        }


        // (create color space, create graphics context, render buffer)
        CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo;

        // basically we decide if it's a grayscale, rgb or rgba image
        if (image.channels() == 1) {
            colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
            bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNone;
        } else if (image.channels() == 3) {
            colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNone;
            if (iOSimage) {
                bitmapInfo |= kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little;
            } else {
                bitmapInfo |= kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big;
            }
        } else {
            colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst;
            if (iOSimage) {
                bitmapInfo |= kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little;
            } else {
                bitmapInfo |= kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big;
            }
        }

        if (iOSimage) {
            context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bufferAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);
            dstImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
            CGContextRelease(context);
        } else {

            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:image.data length:image.elemSize()*image.total()];
            CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

            // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
            dstImage = CGImageCreate(image.cols,                                 // width
                                     image.rows,                                 // height
                                     8,                                          // bits per component
                                     8 * image.elemSize(),                       // bits per pixel
                                     image.step,                                 // bytesPerRow
                                     colorSpace,                                 // colorspace
                                     bitmapInfo,                                 // bitmap info
                                     provider,                                   // CGDataProviderRef
                                     NULL,                                       // decode
                                     false,                                      // should interpolate
                                     kCGRenderingIntentDefault                   // intent
                                     );

            CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        }


        // render buffer
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.customPreviewLayer.contents = (__bridge id)dstImage;
        });


        // cleanup
        CGImageRelease(dstImage);

        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    }
}


@end
```