# Processing live video and still images simultaneously at two different resolutions on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, image-processing, avfoundation

I'm working on video processing app for the iPhone using OpenCV.

For performance reasons, I wan't to process live video at a relatively low resolution. I'm doing object-detection on each frame in the video. When the objects are found in the low-resolution video frame, I need to acquire that exact same frame at a much higher resolution.

I've been able to semi-accomplish this using a videoDataBufferOutput and a stillImageOutput from AVFoundation, but the still image is not the exact frame that I need.

Are there any good implementations of this or ideas on how to implement it myself?

Comment: It is impossible to get the exact same frame, since the sensor can either capture a still image or a video frame at a given moment. You will always have some delay. The closest thing you can do is capture a high resolution video, save the high res frames in memory, resize them and do the object detection in low res, delete the (high-res) frame if the object wasn't found or use it if it was.

Comment: @RosaGronchi Thank you for the reply. Do you know what the minimum delay possible (either time or frame offset) would be between signaling to capture the still image asynchronously and actually getting the frame? If this delay is low enough it might still work for my purposes. I like your idea too but I'm concerned about memory issues in storing all the high-res frames, as I'm already down to ~8fps due to the memory intensive image processing that happens on each frame.

Comment: The minimal delay is phone dependent and is typically very short (.25 second or less on iPhone 5 assuming no flash). You don't need to store all the high res frames, you can only store the ones you are working on at the moment (1-4, depending on whether you are using a single thread or multiple ones)

Answer (score 2):

In AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto it use small video preview(about 1000x700 for iPhone6) and high resolution photo(about 3000x2000).

So I use modified 'CvPhotoCamera' class to process small preview and take photo of full-size picture. I post this code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31478505/1994445